# How can I pick out different values from an API and put them in the same HTML-table head?

Tags: javascript, api, filter, webapi

I am trying to get different values from a web-api so I can compare these values in a table. For example

```
{
"observations": {
"antal": {
"value": 754,
"rojd": false
}
},
"dimensions": {
"ar": "2022",
"vardland_kod": "ALL",
"kon_kod": "K",
"row_nr": "2"
}
},
```

"kon_kod" can have 2 different values (K, M) and I need to get them to compare their "value". So what I need to do is:

Get values K and M from the "kon_kod"-field. From here I need to put them into a HTML-table like this

Land - Year - Men - Women

With the values of men and women underneath in their own row.

Comment: Please don't post image of code, but post the actual code itself

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+compare+object+value+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please improve the problem description. To get all kon_kod you can do this: `const kon_kods = data.map(({dimensions}) => dimensions.kon_kod)`. To get only entries with "K": `const kon_kod_objects = data.filter(({dimensions}) => dimensions.kon_kod === "K")`